# Change Color, Size and Separator of actionbar items

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to do this exactly:

[image]

So to try to achieve that, this is my code:

menu.xml:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/a"
    android:label="A TEXT"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="A TEXT"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/b"
    android:label="A MULTI \n LINE \n TEXT"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="A MULTI \n LINE \n TEXT"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/c"
    android:label="MORE \nTEXT"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="MORE\n TEXT"/>
```

And Themes.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.cataleg" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
   <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/myactionBarStyleWhite</item>
   <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/myactionBarStyleWhite.midaTextViews</item>
</style>

<style name="myactionBarStyleWhite" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#FFffffff</item>
    <item name="android:divider">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:horizontalSpacing">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:height">106dp</item>
</style>

<style name="myactionBarStyleWhite.midaTextViews" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

**However, from all those options, only the textSize property is correctly set. Not the color nor the separator.**

**How can I achieve this?**

I've checked many questions like this, and tried many of them. For example:
Changed

```
    <style name="myactionBarStyleWhite.midaTextViews" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
```

To

```
    <style name="myactionBarStyleWhite.midaTextViews" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you apply the theme you defined to the application (or individual activities)? <application android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" ... />

Comment: It's set via code, so it's individual

Comment: @Bram however I'm setting the whole Theme not the actionBarStyle. Theme sets actionBarStyle.